how to get a file from an URL?
I have a csv file in a web server. The address to the file is http://192.168.1.2/Folder/File.csv.
To can access to the file, I need to use a user and password.
I would like to can get this file to copy it in a local folder.
I an trying to use this code:
internal static async void GetFile()
{
    try
    {
        HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
        handler.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("User", "123456");

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
        var response = await client.GetAsync("http://192.168.1.2/Folder/File.csv");
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

But in the console I get an error: "MyApplication.exe (process 12345) exited with code 0".
If I set a breakpoint in the first line of the catch, the code doesn't get that line, so the exception is not catched. The error happens when I run the last line, calling the GetASync() method.
How could get access to the csv file?
Thanks.

There's no exception. You never check or use the response. For all you know, the call succeeded. At the very least check response.StatusCode. If you don't care about the file name you can use GetStreamAsync instead of Get to either get a stream or an exception

await GetAsync returns HttpResponseMessage and you does nothing with it ... check status, and copy content to file

Does this answer your question? How to copy all the files in a URL?

if I add another line of code like response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); the code doesn't arise to this line. So the code fails in someway in the call of GetAsync().

"async void" ? well ... you are asking for trouble ... and prolly never await GetFile method ...

That's not what your code says. If the code failed there would be an exception which would be caught by catch(Exception ex). We can't guess what you tried. Post code that actually reproduces the problem.

async void that's what prevents the exception handler from working. Use async Task instead, and await the method. async void methods can't be awaited which means any exceptions thrown may be lost. The caller will resume running after the first await inside an async void, the variables in that method will be treated as orphaned objects and execution may never resume. Your application may exit before GetAsync returns at all

Your code doesn't run into any errors. You don't do anything with the response as panagiotis states.
The type of the response variable is a HttpResponseMessage. You can check the status by accessing the StatusCode property.
var response = await client.GetAsync("http://192.168.1.2/Folder/File.csv");
System.Net.HttpStatusCode statusCode = response.StatusCode;
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); // throws error if call was not successful

You can read the content of the response, which in this case is a file, by doing reading the content as a byte array.
byte[] httpResponseMessageContent = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();

Using this byte array you can save it as a file locally or convert it to base64 for other operations.
